# Populate column with average of row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need to find the averages of rows of dynamic length and populate them into a column of dynamic length.

Col C displays the average of (only the fields in the row that contain 1 integer ranging 1-5 and nothing else) to two decimal points.

I've searched extensively but everyone is building code in direct reference to the rows and columns that are populated without and robust consideration for an evolving response.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. You want to take the average of a complete row (so all values in that row) and put it where? It would make sense to give an example of your document and show an example of the output you'd expect.

Comment: AVERAGE(I2:BW2) returns the average of the values through the entire row.
I need to find the average everytime a new row populates, without dragging the function down through the next 1000 rows on the column that is holding the averaged value calculation.

Comment: Hi. Could you provide a sample spreadsheet with simple data? But to provide a brief possible solution right now, you could just implement a checking in `onEdit()` or `onChange()` if content is added, then call `setFormula()` (with your `AVERAGE` formula).